# The dress was too small in the shoulders

Tags: adverbs

The dress was too small in the shoulders.
Why in this sentence does the adverbial phrase (in the shoulder) modify the adjective (small), and not the verb (was)?

What can I read for a clear answer to this question?

Comment: The width of the shoulders was the part of the dress that was too small. How would you expect the sentence to read?

Comment: @KateBunting - I would expect "the dress was too *narrow* in the shoulders".

Comment: @Hot Licks But I wouldn't (though both are used) [Google 5-grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=too+small+in+the+shoulders%2Ctoo+narrow+in+the+shoulders&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctoo%20small%20in%20the%20shoulders%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctoo%20narrow%20in%20the%20shoulders%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - That's 2-grams.

Comment: @Hot Licks No; 2 5-grams.

Answer (score 2):

The locative adjunct *in the shoulders* does not modify *small*, neither does it specify the location of *the dress* or the situation as a whole. It serves to indicate which part of the dress was *too small*. It is approximately equivalent to:

> The shoulders of the dress were too small.

The relevant question to the sentence given would be:

> Where is the dress too small?

A discussion of similar cases may be found in CaGEL (*the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*) pages 681-682.